# Ideas to improve the stability of a test environment

Tags: testing, microservices, environment

Our application is built on a microservice architecture. The test environment is sometimes down due to failures in some of the downstream services. What are some good practices to follow that would have a stable test environment.
Looking for ideas that are popular in the industry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a dashboard that includes results from some tests that are checking which services are up and send notifications to responsible people when some services are down so that they can fix them.

Comment: thank you! That sound great. Are there any tools that are recommended to create the dashboard.

Comment: It can be Jenkins, Azure DevOps, basically any tool that provides continuous integration is a good candidate.